# How to hardcode header and footer in WP?

Tags: php, templates

I am playing with optimizing a site built on Divi. I'm thinking that rigidly embedding the footer and header will have a positive effect on page speed - just not quite sure how to go about it. I don't need all the know-how, just some guidance. Ideally, after rigid embedding it would still be possible to edit the contents of the header and footer.

Any idea?

Comment: Hello! Since 3rd party plugin questions are considered to be off-topic here; this type of question may be better asked via [Divi Support](https://www.elegantthemes.com/forum/) directly. It might also be worth to look into the basics of [Theme Development](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/) via the [WordPress Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/who-should-read-this-handbook/).

Answer (score 0):

You can always edit header.php and footer.php manually and entering HTML there, just be sure to call appropriate DIVI functions like

```
    elegant_description();
    elegant_keywords();
    elegant_canonical();
    do_action( 'et_head_meta' );
```

etc., and WordPress `wp_head();` and others. Be warned that DIVI does a lot of tweaking and you must call necessary functions and find which are not necessary, so such optimization would not be an easy thing. WordPress's default header.php is much simpler than DIVI's.
In the end, you might not feel much of optimization, since all DIVI functions must load for the middle (content) part of the page.
I think it would be better concentrating on caching and optimizations with plugins like WP Super Cache, Phastpress or recent WP Meteor.
Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this older post
elegant_description();
elegant_keywords();
elegant_canonical();

I was using my own coded META desc/tag - and when DIVI plugin needed to update, the header.php file was always overwriting the META & The Google A/TM/Scripts.  It was what you said Lovor about the "middle (content) that I looked more into it and noticed that DIVI doesn't like hard coded.

The SEO part is in the Menu DIVI > SEO sliders.
The Google A/TM tags also go there under INTEGRATION